# Using quote delimiter in SQL SELECT statement for escaping single quote

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I want to escape single quote when a user enters an input text such as "Sam's project deliverable" in a form entry developed in C# (.NET). Database is ORACLE 10g.

I came across Quote delimiter feature offered from ORACLE 10g http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_FAQ#How_does_one_escape_special_characters_when_writing_SQL_queries.3F but I am not sure if using such a quote delimiter **q'[ some text with single quote]'** as part of a SELECT statement would **prevent SQL Injection attacks**?

Example usage of quote delimiter q'[ text with single quote ]':

```
SQL> SELECT q'[Frank's Oracle site]' AS text FROM DUAL;
 TEXT
 -------------------
 Frank's Oracle site

 SQL> SELECT q'[A 'quoted' word.]' AS text FROM DUAL;
 TEXT
 ----------------
 A 'quoted' word.

 SQL> SELECT q'[A ''double quoted'' word.]' AS text FROM DUAL;
 TEXT
 -------------------------
 A ''double quoted'' word.
```

Comment: and your problem is...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection will help you out.

Comment: @MarcB: Sorry Marc there was some issue while posting the question. Now my post should explain my problem/question

Comment: It won't prevent injection. It will probably slow down half-hearted attempts because the attackers will assume the end delimiter is `'` and get nowhere. But a pro won't stop there and with brute force they can break the quote literal easily enough.

Comment: No - this will not prevent injection attacks.  The ONLY thing that will prevent injection attacks is to NEVER build dynamic SQL statements with user-entered data directly in the SQL text; i.e. ALWAYS access the user-entered data through parameters markers.  ALL-WAYS!!!

Comment: @BobJarvis: Examples please?

Comment: [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3bba/1) is an example for sql injection with `--` instead of `'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your query looks anything like this...

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE name = q'[" + <what the user entered> + "]'";
```

... and the user enters something like this...

```
abc]';<harmful statement>;SELECT * FROM DUAL WHERE '1'=q'[1
```

... they'll have a successful injection.

It won't matter which delimiters you use with the `q` - a determined attacker will try them all. Prepared statements are your best defense.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. Your response helped me understand how frail the q delimiter is.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all single quotes with 2 single quotes before executing the SQL. i.e. replace ' with '' before executing the SQL command.

In C#:

```
string sql = originalString.Replace("'", "''");
```

Comment: it's much safer to use parameterised queries, if you can.

Comment: @Martyn: Thanks for your answer. I am just trying to explore the option of using quote delimiter q'[ ]' and how safe it is? And if it prevents injection?

Comment: @penguat: thanks for the link and suggestion. I will look into it.

Comment: I understand. This article probably helps more than I can - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544484/how-to-do-sql-injection-on-oracle

Comment: @penguat: does string sql = originalString.Replace("'", "''"); comes under parameterised query? (I am a beginner please apologize for my lack of understanding of a parameterised query)

Comment: No - I believe parameterised queries send the query with placeholders to the database, and then the user input to fill the placeholders. try searching "_c# oracle parameterised query example_"